# Yo error encode not defined when generating webapp

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I get the following when I run yo webapp from the cmd line after following http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zBt2g9ekiug to about 3 minutes. Has anyone seen this before?

```
   C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\node_modules\cheeri
o\node_modules\entities\index.js:36
        return encode[level](data);
               ^
ReferenceError: encode is not defined
    at Object.exports.encode (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\genera
tor-webapp\node_modules\cheerio\node_modules\entities\index.js:36:9)
    at exports.encode (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-web
app\node_modules\cheerio\lib\utils.js:41:50)
    at formatAttrs (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp
\node_modules\cheerio\lib\render.js:30:32)
    at renderTag (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\n
ode_modules\cheerio\lib\render.js:113:18)
    at C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\node_modules
\cheerio\lib\render.js:81:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ge
nerator-webapp\node_modules\cheerio\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)

    at module.exports (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-web
app\node_modules\cheerio\lib\render.js:77:5)
    at Object.exports.html (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generato
r-webapp\node_modules\cheerio\lib\static.js:40:12)
    at Appgenerator.domUpdate (C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gener
ator-webapp\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\actions\wiring.js:44:14)
```

Comment: I get the same thing with generator-angular very frustrating!

Comment: Very helpful as I'm working towards an angular app :)

Comment: same problem with generator-ember

Comment: I haven't tried the generator-webapp but generator-angular is working as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to use the cg-angular yeoman generator:

```
sudo npm install -g generator-cg-angular
yo cg-angular
```

Obviously not ideal if you're following a tutorial though.

Comment: Thanks I'm accepting as it got me past where I'm stuck, I've also opened an issue on github

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue when follow tutorial with latest Yomen version.
There is typo error in entities library that You can manually fix to complete tutorial:

Open file with error (in your case C:\Users\L\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-webapp\node_modules\cheerio\node_modules\entities\index.js ) and change variable name from inverse to encode

```
var decode = levels.map(function(l){ return l.normal; }),
    decodeStrict = levels.map(function(l){ return l.strict; }),
    inverse = levels.map(function(l){ return l.inverse; });
```

To

```
var decode = levels.map(function(l){ return l.normal; }),
    decodeStrict = levels.map(function(l){ return l.strict; }),
    encode = levels.map(function(l){ return l.inverse; });
```

Comment: This solved it for me too. I see there's already a pull request on github's entities resolving this issue. It's sad some libs choose to ignore the testing-before-committing approach.

Answer (score 1):

Also happening in OSX for angular generator:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/entities/index.js:36
    return encode[level](data);
           ^
ReferenceError: encode is not defined
at Object.exports.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/entities/index.js:36:9)
at exports.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/lib/utils.js:41:50)
at formatAttrs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/lib/render.js:30:32)
at renderTag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/lib/render.js:114:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/lib/render.js:82:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/lib/render.js:78:5)
at Object.exports.html (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cheerio/lib/static.js:40:12)
at Generator.domUpdate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/wiring.js:39:14)
```

Comment: I thought I was just doing something stupid but I'll open a bug in the  yeoman github and link this

Answer (score 0):

The Node module entities just released a new version breaking a dependency (cheerio) of yeoman.

Comment: Is it worth reporting to yeoman or do they know at this point? Any workaround?

Comment: Probably best to cheerio so they pin entities to ~0.3.0, haven't found anything yet to work around.

Comment: That is no option for me. But opened a pull request: https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio/pull/382

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to originate to cheerio. Issue opened here https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio/pull/382

Comment: Correct, see answer above ;)